# Correct way to handle the NULL char when dealing with char arrays

Tags: c, arrays

Is there a way to correctly handle the NUL character whenever we're handling c-style string or char arrays?

```
int myint;
char stringa[4];            
memset(stringa, 0x0, 4);
memset(stringa, ' ', 3);

stringa = getValueS();
myint = getValue();

char stringint[4];
memset(stringint, 0x0, 4);
memset(stringint, ' ', 3);

itoa(myint, stringint, 10);

char finals[7];
memset(finals, 0x0, 7);
memset(finals, ' ', 6);

memcpy(&finals[3], stringint, 3);
memcpy(&finals[0], stringa, 3);
```

finals gives "0"

stringint gives "0"

stringa gives "0"

expected return "0  0  "

Comment: "0" != NULL. `'\0'` is the null character in a char array, and you can't print it out, because it's a NULL character - there's nothing to print.

Comment: you mean "0x0" != NULL?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. A NULL character is `\0` in a char array, just as I wrote in my last comment. I'm not sure how I'm not being clear here. `0x0` != `\0`, either. `((0x0 == 0) && (0x0 != '\0'))`

Comment: in the code, the value in myint must be -99 <= myint <= 999.  Otherwise, the atoi() function will output more char than are available in the stringint array

Comment: Is there anyway way I can fix my code to get "0  0  " at the end?

Comment: what do you mean by 'gives;? do you mean when you perform: printf( "%d", ... );  or do you mean: printf( "%s", ... );?  what is output will depend heavily on the value in myint.  And all arrays defined in the code would need to be printed using the "%s" format string

Comment: I used cout for all 3 of them.

Comment: now I'm confused.  the null byte at the end of a string contains 0x00, which is the same as '\0' which is the same as 0x0.

Comment: how do you want to get "0 0 "?  perhaps using cout (assuming that the appropriate include statement is at the front of the code.  you could set an array to 0x3020302000 ('0', ' ', '0', ' ', '\0') then use cout to print that array

Comment: I suspect there is something wrong with your setup, as cout << finals << endl; should output 3 spaces.  (similar comments for the other arrays.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that *you* want to handle it. There is no need for this. The [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/?kw=itoa) function does this for you. The string that is stored in the array passed as parameter is NUL-terminated.

**Be careful**, itoa is not a standard function, so your code might not be portable. You could write a custom itoa.

Now, a few words about your code:

1. Filling the array with zeros might solve the NUL problem, although is bad practice. The function which manage the data from that array must ensure the presence of NUL terminator, regardless of the array's content (take a look at functions like [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/?kw=strcpy)).
2. There is no point in filling the array with a character such as empty spaces.
3. I don't know what `getValueS()` is doing, but it seems that it returns a pointer to char (at least you're assigning the result to a pointer to char). If that's the case, the initialisation you've done to `stringa` are useless, as it will point to another memory location (so you can't access your array anymore).

If my answer is not clear enough, please add more information: post the full code, including declarations for `getValue()`, `getValueS()` and the main function.